# XPATH needed for specific node(s) by attribute match

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, exslt

**GIVEN XML**

```
<lists>
<list>
<param type="a">content</param>
</list>
<list>
<param type="b">content2</param>
</list>
<list>
<param type="a">content</param>
<param type="b">content2</param>
</list>
<list>
<param type="c">content3</param>
</list>
</lists>
```

1. I need to process any `list/param[@type = 'a'|'b']` and I can do that, but I want the whole `parent:list` and loop when there may be more than one `child::param` and I can do that. I'm just not sure how to get the entire parent node with **any param attribute** based on the match of type 'a' or type 'b'. (XPATH needed)
2. then I need to process any `list` **without** a `param[@type = 'a'|'b']`, and I can do that. But need the correct XPATH to get that as I'm going through the `lists`

My template right now just matches "list", but need a "branch"? choose/when/otherwise (?) - I'm not sure I have the XPATH syntax right.
Thanks, I'm just trying to save time without trial and error!

I tried a lot of things, and *know* I have the incorrect paths.
So just seeing if I have anything off.

Comment: I cannot figure out what your question is. Please add your current XSLT and the exact output you are trying to get.

Comment: P.S. Do note that `[@type = 'a'|'b']` is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: the expression is NOT valid, that's why I asked for a valid XPATH. I cannot post the XSLT. Given the example XML I just want the valid path
Give me any `list` that has any child `param` with the `type` attribute of 'a' OR 'b'
Then give any `list` that does **not** match those types. So any `list` with `param` that does not have 'a' OR 'b' as one of its `type` attributes.

Comment: in my example, `list[1]`, `list[2]`, & `list[3]` would match one type of process. `list[4]` would match another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath for a list with `a` or `b`

```
list[param[@type[. = 'a' or . = 'b']]]
```

The XPath for a list without `a` or `b`

```
list[not(param[@type[. = 'a' or . = 'b']])]
```

OR

The XPath for a list with `a` or `b`

```
list[param[contains('ab', @type]]
```

The XPath for a list without `a` or `b`

```
list[not(param[contains('ab', @type])]
```

Comment: contains(), of course! thank you @siebe! we get rusty when we must fix old code. LOL

Comment: Depending on your demands you can play with the `not()`